# NextJS [v13.5.3] - shows default 404 page instead of a custom 404 page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, localhost, custom-error-pages

I have a `custom error page` which is showing if a user goes to the non-existing page path and/or when a user is looking for a non-existing product.
Everything worked as expected on a `"nextjs": "13.4.19"`, but after updating `nextjs` on version `v13.5.3` this is not the case anymore, at least not locally.
Instead of showing a custom error page now I get a default 404 page, which breaks cypress tests as well.

I've already downgraded the `nextjs` version from `v13.5.4` to `v13.5.3`, but this doesn't solve this problem of showing a default 404 instead of a custom 404 page. Also, making a mocked page path for the cypress test doesn't resolve the problem as well.
I couldn't find anything in their changelogs what could be the reason for a breaking changes in my case.

Custom error page is inside the `pages` folder.

Does anyone have any idea why in a new version a custom 404 is not working anymore?